# What is a common approach to scope records by those that an user can "read"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, activerecord, authorization

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to know what is a common approach when it must be checked if an user has proper authorizations to "read" records present in a "list" of records. That is, at this time I have the following:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def readable_by_user?(user)
    # Implementation of multiple authorization checks that are not easy to
    # translate into an SQL query (at database level, it executes a bunch of
    # "separate" / "different" SQL queries).

    ... # return 'true' or 'false'
  end
end
```

By using the above code I can perform authorization checks on a *single* article object:

```
@article.readable_by_user?(@current_user)
```

However, when I would like to make (usually, in my controller `index` action) something like the following by retrieving exactly 10 objects

```
Article.readable_by_user(@current_user).search(...).paginate(..., :per_page => 10)
```

I must still to perform authorization checks on each object. So, ***what I can make to perform authorization checks on that "list" of records*** (an array of `Article` objects) ***in a "smart" / "performant" way?*** That is, for example, should I load `Article.all` (maybe ordering those by created data, limiting the SQL query to 10 records, ...) and then to iterate on each of those objects so to perform authorization checks? or should I make something different (maybe with some SQL query trick, some Ruby on Rails facility or something else)?

## UPDATED after @Matzi answer

I tried to retrieve articles *readable* by an user "manually", for example by using the [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each) method:

```
# Note: This method is intended to be used as a "scope" method
#
#   Article.readable_by_user(@current_user).search(...).paginate(..., :per_page => 10)
#
def self.readable_by_user(user, n = 10)
  readable_article_ids = []

  Article.find_each(:batch_size => 1000) do |article|
    readable_article_ids << article.id if article.readable_by_user?(user)

    # Breaks the block when 10 articles have passed the readable authorization 
    # check.
    break if readable_article_ids.size == n
  end

  where("articles.id IN (?)", readable_article_ids)
end
```

At this time, the above code is the most "performant compromise" that I can think of, even if it has some pitfall: it "*restricts*" the amount of retrieved objects to a given amount of records with given `id`s (10 records by default in the above example); practically speaking, *it "really" doesn't retrieve all objects readable by an user* since when you try to further scope the related `ActiveRecord::Relation` "where" / "with which" the `readable_by_user` scope method is used (for example, when you would also search articles by `title` adding a further SQL query clause), it would *restrict* records to those `where("articles.id IN (?)", readable_article_ids)` (that is, it "limits" / "restricts" the amount of retrieved and readable objects to first 10 and all others articles *readable* by the user will be ignored when searching by `title`). A solution to the issue in order to make the `readable_by_user` method to properly work with further scope methods could be to do *not* `break` the block so to load all *readable* articles, but it is no good for performance reasons when there are a lot of records (maybe, another solution could be to store somewhere all article `id`s readable by an user, but I think it is not a common/easy solution to solve the issue).

So, ***there is some way to accomplish what I would like to make in a performant and "really" correct way (maybe, by changing the above approach at all)?***

Comment: May we have the full code for `readable_by_user?` ?

Comment: @patrickmcgraw - For "Privacy policy" reasons I have not authorization to post the full code of the `readable_by_user?` method. I can say you that, at database level, it executes a bunch of "separate" / "different" SQL queries.

Comment: Ok, just thought I'd ask. I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around how you could have a set of tables that can't be related via SQL. Especially when SQL is already processing the tables individually to achieve the intended purpose. Does any of the `readable_by_user?` check depend on something completely outside of the database, such as application state?

Comment: @patrickmcgraw - Thank you for your understanding related to the "Privacy policy". My answer is: No, the `readable_by_user?` check does *not* depend on something completely outside of the database.

Comment: If so you should provide any example near to your implementation of the `readable_by_user?` to give us food for further reflection.

Comment: Authorization through DB logic is the performant approach. You can describe your authorization logic in generic terms. It will help the community to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your `readable_by_user` function. If it is easy to translate into an SQL, than it is the way forward. If it is more complicated than that then you most probably have to do the check manually.

UPDATE:
To clarify the point of creating an SQL query for the readable list I present an example.
Assume, that a readability of an article to a given user is dependent of the following:

- The user's own article (`SELECT a.user == ? FROM Articles a WHERE a.id = ?`)
- The article is open to everyone (`SELECT a.state == 0 FROM Articles a WHERE a.user = ?`)
- The user is member of a group with access to articles

sql:

```
SELECT max(g.rights) > 64
FROM Groups g 
JOIN Groups_users gu on g.id = ug.group_id
WHERE gu.id = ?
```

- The user is assigned to the given article

sql:

```
SELECT 1
FROM Articles_users au
WHERE au.article_id = ? AND au.user_id = ?
```

These can be summarized in the following query:

```
def articles_for_user(user) 
  Articles.find_by_sql(["
    SELECT a.*
    FROM Articles a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Articles_users au on au.article_id = a.id and au.user_id = ?
    WHERE a.user_id = ? 
       OR au.user_id = ?
       OR 64 <= (SELECT max(g.rights) 
                 FROM Groups g 
                 JOIN Groups_users gu on g.id = ug.group_id
                 WHERE gu.id = ?)
  ", user.id, user.id, user.id, user.id])
end
```

This is sure a complicated query, but the most efficient solution. The database should do database stuff, if you only use SQL queries and some logic to evaluate your `readable_bu_user` then you can translate it into one pure SQL query.

Comment: Using a select block or other conventional method of travering the array and select the ones you need.

Comment: If the `readable_by_user` only depends on SQL, then the best way is to create an SQL query for the list. Article.find_by_sql(["Select ...", user.id]). If you insist on using the `readable_by_user`function then do not just collect the id-s, collect the objects itself as they are already in the memory, no need to query them again by id. Any further optimalization depends on the system, e.g. the rarity of readable articles, rules of readability, etc...

Comment: How / Where should I "insist"? I do not understand how you would proceed in order to set up the structure of the method "to create an SQL query for the list".

Comment: Updated with an example, I hope this highlights the point. The exact code and structure is dependent of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you sholud look for [declarative_authorization gem](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization). With its `with_permissions_to` method you can easily perfom such database queries. For example: `Article.with_permissions_to(:read).limit(10).offset(20)`

Comment: I tried to use the `declarative_authorization` gem, but it doesn't accomplish what I would like to make because my `readable_by_user`, as Matzi said, "is *not* easy to translate into an SQL". I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The [cancan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) has this functionality. In fact, as of version 1.4 it will automatically scope your queries to return objects that are accessible to the current user.

See this page for more info: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Fetching-Records

Comment: I tried to use the `cancan` gem, but it doesn't accomplish what I would like to make because my `readable_by_user`, as Matzi said, "is *not* easy to translate into an SQL". I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a system I'm currently worked on.

The most efficient way I found was to implement a batch job that pre-calculates the authorization state of each record. I went with something like `accessible_by_companies` and stored an array with all the company codes that could access those records, but you might as well work with `accessible_by_users` if that's your case.

On the "show" action, I recalculate the list of authorized companies for the record, use it to perform the authorization check, and store it again.

I used [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) to store the pre-calculated values and all the data I needed to perform queries and listings. The database is only touched when viewing a record or by the batch job. There's a big performance gain on this approach, give it a try.

Comment: *Can you be a little more explicit, maybe by providing some simple code?* P.S.: I already considered the solution to store an Array with all object `id`s "readable" / "accessible" by an user, but as I mention in the question content "I think it is *not* a common/easy solution to solve the issue" (mostly because you must care to keep that Array updated). However, if I understood what you make, in the "show" controller action you update the Array of `id`s related to the current object shown, but making so only objects that the user "has already shown" can be readable (all other, are ignored).

Answer (score 0):

For best performance I would suggest storing list of user readable articles in the session - the user is not going to change within the session and you may consider refresh frequency and/or conditions separately. Assuming that your Articles.list() can be filtered by ids all you will need to do will be to pass the list of user readable ids to Articles.list() functionality.
Re user readable list update: you should really update it relatively infrequently - at most once per search, you don' t want to refresh the complete list on every page load for the simple reason that the new results may appear in the pages that user already scrolled through anyway.